# Closest match with Two tables of coordinates MySQL using Haversine formula

Tags: mysql, join, recursion, subquery, geospatial

I believe that is more of a subquery\join question than a geospatial one.

Essentially i have two tables. One table is structured

```
EVENTS
ID | LAT | LNG |
```

Second table is

```
POI 
|POIID | LAT | LNG |
```

The following query works for a given coordinate to get back the closest POI

```
SELECT 
poiid,  
(
   6371 *
   acos(cos(radians(-32.8857)) * 
   cos(radians(lat)) * 
   cos(radians(lng) - 
   radians(151.7661)) + 
   sin(radians(-32.8857)) * 
   sin(radians(lat)))
) AS distance 
FROM POI
=ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

What i want is pretty much a recursive thing on the Events table, essentially gives me an output of

```
OUTPUT

    |ID| LAT | LONG | *Closest* POIID |
```

I have tried to do this in the select query

```
`Select A.ID, A.LAT, A.LONG (SELECT the Haversine formula with A.LAT and  A.LONG) from EVENTS A`
```

but MySQL, or i believe any SQL can’t do multiple return values on a select in a select, and i think theres an issue here of calculation across the select??

Hope this makes sense; any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this without doing a full outer join of the tables to make a list of all distances - which is space intensive - and then joining that on itself to select the minimum for each event - which is computationally intensive. The following should work, but might not scale well:

`WITH distances AS 
(
  SELECT p.poiid, e.id, p.lat AS lat, p.lng AS lng,
  (
     6371 *
     acos(cos(radians(p.lat)) * 
     cos(radians(e.lat)) * 
     cos(radians(e.lng) - 
     radians(p.lng)) + 
     sin(radians(p.lat)) * 
     sin(radians(e.lat)))
  ) AS distance 
  FROM poi p CROSS JOIN events e
)
SELECT * FROM distances d1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(distance) AS min_dis, id FROM distances GROUP BY id) d2
  ON d1.id = d2.id AND d1.distance = d2.min_dis;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It does work, but just as you mentioned it is very intensive on process.. ironically cant use CTEs in MySQL but they have just published a draft for there new verion yesterday introducing CTEs..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your use case... but I would suggest calculating the closest POI once for each event, storing it, and then writing something to update it when a new event or POI is added that only involves a single pass through one table or the other (such as your example) rather than having to do the cross join and do n^2 as much work.